# html2canvas.js | Send image to variable for server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas

I am creating a custom graduation stole configurator with jquery and codeigniter. I have got everything how I want it now and my plan is to use html2canvas to take a screenshot of the stole div when they click the add to cart button. I need to just pass this image to a hidden input value or something so that I can write the image to the server.

The stole configurator can be viewed here: [custom stole configurator](http://faithpointdallas.com/ecom/page/customStole). When you click the Add to Cart button it currently generates the image of the stole and it looks like its working fairly well.

I'm just stuck on the best way or ANY way to put the URL to that image in a hidden input or somehow move the image to a folder and write a path to it.

My point in doing this is so that in the shopping cart there can be a link to "custom stole preview" and when they click on it, it shows this canvas render.

Any help on how I could accomplish this would be of great help. Thanks.

By the way, here is the JS that is doing the screen shot:

```
$('#addToCart').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
 $('div.customstole').html2canvas();
 var queue = html2canvas.Parse();
 var canvas = html2canvas.Renderer(queue,{elements:{length:1}});
 var img = canvas.toDataURL();
 $('body').append(img);
```

});

EDIT:

```
$('#addToCart').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
     $('div.customstole').html2canvas();
     var queue = html2canvas.Parse();
     var canvas = html2canvas.Renderer(queue,{elements:{length:1}});
     $('#dataUrl').val(canvas.toDataURL());
});
```

Comment: Very annoying: A "Do you want to leave this page" popup when you close the window, even if you only open the page and not change anything.

Comment: And another thing... obviously to YOU that feature is annoying, but the person who has just spent 15 minutes creating a custom stole and accidentally backs out of the page will appreciate it.

Comment: Then make it so, that the popup only shows when something has changed. BTW There's no need to be offensive. That I have a +1 on my comment already says there are people who agree with me. See it as positive criticism to improve your site, instead of cursing people!

Comment: not helpful and not the question. could care less about that when i've been working on something for 2 weeks. If you're not directly answering the question then pass on to another one. People don't want your pesky little comments inserting into problems that they're trying to get help on.

Answer (score 0):

Write the data URL to a hidden input, and then on the server side, `base64_decode()` it and write an image from the resulting string.

Comment: I have created a hidden input called #dataUrl and I put the following code (edited into response) in but it doesn't change the value of the hidden input with anything...